# How do you define whether or not a question needs to be deleted?

Tags: support

How do you figure out whether or not a question needs to be deleted. It's not a duplicate. The only problem with it is it is extremely subject to that one person and probably will not help or effect anyone? It is a new user and by the looks of it looks like he is just grasping a random question for some reputation.

Comment: Same question at MSO: [When should I vote to delete?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842/162827)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally all questions that get closed should be deleted, except for the questions closed as duplicate. Some questions manage to get the 3 votes/1 moderator to delete them after a while, others fall through the (wide) cracks. There's really no rhyme or reason to deletion, except for the part where particularly bad posts attract more attention from our reviewers/voters.

Comment: Whya re duplicates not deleted immediatly?

Comment: Because they help to get traffic from search engines, as they are the same question with different words

Comment: Whether a question is deleted or not sometimes comes down to something as simple as whether there are three people around to cast deletion votes.

Comment: @kalina That's my answer entirely.

Comment: I thought that's what we did now? Follow each other around on meta and sum up what we each said in the comments? :p